application.properties doesn't recognize datasource prefix
I am trying to set up 2 separate dabases for my project. I created 2 new datasources for each database and for some reason my application.properties file doesnt recognize the prefixes I set in the datasource configuration.
Here is the primary datasource config:
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.groman.healthis.db1.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager"
)
public class MysqlDataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.mysql")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("mysqlDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.groman.healthis.db1.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("mysql")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("mysqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}

and here the application.properties part with which I'm trying to connect to it:
spring.datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HealthIS
spring.datasource.mysql.username=groman
spring.datasource.mysql.password=password
spring.datasource.mysql.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.mysql.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.mysql.show-sql=true

I get this and a bunch of other errors that seem related to each other, it looks to Spring can't find those properties to db connect. Why?
java. lang. IllegalArgumentException Create breakpoint: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName. at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikaniConfiq.iava:1028) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:nal
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnectionHikaniDataSource.java:108) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar:nal ‹16 internal lines>
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.orm. jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactoryAbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory-doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.Lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingLetonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory-doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.14.jar:6.1.141
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.14.jar:6.1.14] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerAppLicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.51
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.51
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.5] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.51 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.5.jar:3.3.51
at com.groman.healthis.HealthIsApplication.main(HealthIsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

I tried changing the prefix to the different one, didn't help. In all the tutorials I saw it done like this.
